Flutter and Dart Binary Path problem(macos)
While installing flutter using the official documentation, I am getting the following outputs through VS code when I was installing flutter SDK.
What do they mean and how do I correct them?
! The flutter binary is not on your path. Consider adding /Users/gauravkumar/Documents/development/flutter/bin to your path.
    ! The dart binary is not on your path. Consider adding /Users/gauravkumar/Documents/development/flutter/bin to your path.

And the last message is
! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.


To run Flutter commands in the Terminal, add Flutter to the PATH environment variable. Probably, in your case you added it to temporary path which just vanishes if you close the terminal. To add to actual path you need:

Open the terminal
Type nano ~/.zshrc
Type: export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH
Save, by first control+x and click yes
Type: source ~/.zshrc
Restart your terminal
Check the flutter version by flutter --version

Here, PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY is the directory to your flutter folder. I usually put mine in Documents folder.
If problem still remains, include which steps you did and share your .zshrc file.

If you install your Flutter with Puro (https://puro.dev), it will enable multiple versions of flutter installed on a per-project basis, but also handle the initial setup of your .zshrc.  Quite slick.

@RandalSchwartz didn't hear about it, but sounds cool indeed, but not quite sure if someone would need different version of flutter as main requirement would be to use the latest version of flutter.

"main requirement would be to use the latest version of flutter"  Puro can track stable just fine, as well as fix the dotfiles on initial release.  But when you need a project with a downrev dart/flutter, you can quickly bring that up provided you start with puro.

@RandalSchwartz yes, for sure that package is indeed really good, not (and would not) saying against it.

Unfortunately, did not hear from OP yet, I guess problem is solved.
